# Filtering tokens from a list by multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, token, counter

I want to filer some tokens from a list by the following conditions.
1) token length greater than 5
2) the frequency of appearance (in the original text) more than 100

I used the following code

```
#token_list is a list object containing tokenized words from raw text

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(token_list)
selected_tokens = [word for word in token_list if len(word) > 5 and c.item[2] > 100]

selected_tokens
```

But can't seem to get it. I believe the error came from 'c.item[2]' but don't quite understand the mechanics behind the 'Counter()' command.

It will be really appreciated if someone could enlighten me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Literally the first sentence in [the `Counter` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) tells you how to work with them: "A Counter is a dict subclass". If you're going to use a class or function, you'd do well to read its docs first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did someone say `filter`?

```
selected_tokens = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 5 and c[x] > 100, token_list))
```

Also, you access the counter count using `c[...]`. Also, you might want to be wary of case issues (the same word present in different case).

---

If you want speed, use a list comprehension instead:

```
selected_tokens = [x for x in token_list if len(x) > 5 and c[x] > 100]
```

If you are looking to obtain words satisfying your condition without unwanted duplicates, work on a `set` instead of a set:

```
token_set = set(token_list)
selected_tokens = [x for x in token_set if if len(x) > 5 and c[x] > 100]
```

Beware, order is lost. If you want order without duplicates, use an `OrderedDict` (python < 3.6 or `dict` (python >= 3.6).

```
dict_ = OrderedDict()
for t in token_list:
    dict_[t] = None

selected_tokens = [x for x in dict_ if len(x) > 5 and c[x] > 100]
```

If a `dict` doesn't do it, you can look at the [`OrderedSet`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) recipe and implement something to the same effect:

```
token_set = OrderedSet(token_list)
selected_tokens = [x for x in token_set if ...] # as usual
```

Comment: Because from my previous attempts, Counter() returns output of this form '[('token1', freq1), ('token2, freq2)]'.  Hence, I used Counter().item[2] to access 'frequency.'

Comment: @ChrisT. That's only the repr playing tricks on you. You still access it as a normal dict.

Comment: @ChrisT. Also, did you mean to filter on `set(token_list)`? This way, you obtain duplicates

Comment: oh stop, why you need to use here slow filter instead of generator?

Comment: @Reishin Because OP said `filter` in his post. :p Will add alternative solutions, hold on.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! it really helps.

Comment: @ChrisT. Glad I could help! Have added a few extra solutions if it helps.

Comment: Thanks again. I will read through additional code and try them on my token_list.